# What is the meaning of the gpgcheck in repo file?

Tags: repo

In the `.repo` file:

```
[centos]    
name=centos7.2   
baseurl=http://10.0.0.1/centos7.2/7.2/xxx/x86_64/   
enabled=1   
gpgcheck=0
```

You can see there is some key-value analogy things, I know the name, baseurl and enable representative for what, but I don't know what is the use of `gpgcheck`, someone can help with that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

gpgcheck
If set to 1, verify the authenticity of the packages by checking the GPG signatures. You might need to set gpgcheck to 0 if a package is unsigned, but you should be wary that the package could have been maliciously altered.

Answer (score 3):

`gpgcheck=value`
…where value is one of:

- **0** - Disable GPG signature-checking on packages in all repositories, including local package installation.
- **1** - Enable GPG signature-checking on all packages in all repositories, including local package installation. gpgcheck=1 is the default, and thus all packages' signatures are checked.

`enabled=value`
…where value is one of:

- **0** - Do not include this repository as a package source when performing updates and installs. This is an easy way of quickly turning repositories on and off, which is useful when you desire a single package from a repository that you do not want to enable for updates or installs.
- **1** - Include this repository as a package source.